# What would be a good translation/equivalent saying for "Something came up"?

Tags: idiom, saying

I had an appointment, and the other party never showed up. I wanted to send a polite text to say something like, "I assume something came up. Let me know when you have time to talk later." Despite long searching through Leo, Linguee, and Duden, I could not find any recommendations for either a near-literal translation OR a sufficient equivalent for the situation. Does anyone have advice on a phrase that could work here for "something came up"?

Comment: I entered "came up" in the dictionary: https://www.dict.cc/?s=came+up

Comment: Ah ok! Well that's a dictionary I've never heard of before, but it seems to be quite helpful with phrasal stuff! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ich nehme an, dir/Ihnen ist etwas dazwischengekommen

Comment: A brief explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Gigili Other than a bit of verbal decoration, I can't really explain a lot, I'm afraid. What we have here is a straightforward translation of an English expression to a German one.

Comment: Right, you could for example add the translation of important words, such as annehmen and dazwischengekommen or link to their definition in the dictionary. Please note that German.SE does not provide translation/proofread.